# Count expressions

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote some code to solve the problem where a given array shall be evaluated to see if an expression can sum, subtract, or multiply to the target.

Sample output:

- nums = [1, 2, 3] and target = 6 → 2 (expressions: 1 + 2 + 3, 1 * 2 * 3)
- nums = [1, 2, 5] and target = 7 → 1 (expression: 1 * 2 + 5)
- nums = [0, 0] and target = 0 → 3 (expressions: 0 - 0, 0 + 0, 0 * 0)

My code is as follows:

```
def count_expressions(nums, target):
    return count_helper(nums,target, 0)

def count_helper(nums,target,current):
    if len(nums) == 0:
        if current == target:
            return 1
        return 0
    return count_helper(nums[1:],target,target-current) + \
           count_helper(nums[1:],target,target+current) + \
           count_helper(nums[1:],target,current//target)
```

The issue I'm having is that the first call should return 1 and second 0 and third one, but when I call it it returns 6. I trying running each call to see if its returning the correct output and it is the issue starts when I call it all together. Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: Have you tried dry running the approach, if not try, that might clear some doubts

Comment: Do u mean doing each run one by one ??

Comment: Yes, that is usually a good practice to understand your algorithms but, if you want you use tools and/or libraries for visualization, one such library I know is `recursion-visualiser `, [link to the pypi documentation](https://pypi.org/project/recursion-visualiser/#:~:text=Recursion%20visualiser%20is%20a%20python,the%20rest%20of%20the%20work.)

Comment: It looks like this problem doesn't have a trivial or simple solution. Please post all conditions and restrictions. For example, according to your samples: `a + b`, `a - b`, `b - a` are three distinct cases if `a != b`, but `a - b` and `b - a` are the single case if `a == b`. Also, are parentheses allowed?